# A line on a torus intersecting a region

Tags: regions, coding-style

I have a two-dimensional function that is periodic in both variables. We can then think of this function on the surface of a torus. Now imagine a line that endlessly spirals and wraps around the torus. I need to know the distribution of lengths that the line spends in regions where the function is above a set value.  I will give some demo code and my current solution which works, but it does not scale well.

An example function `T`:

```
Clear[S, T];
S[f_, q_, i_, r_] := 
 Evaluate[RotationMatrix[i, {0, 0, 1}].RotationMatrix[
 f, {0, 1, 0}].RotationMatrix[q, {0, 0, 1}].{r, 0, 0}]
T[f_, q_, i_, r_, l_] := 
 ArcCos[(RotationMatrix[l, {0, 1, 0}].{1, 0, 0}).S[f, q, i, r]/Sqrt[
   S[f, q, i, r].S[f, q, i, r]]]
```

Simple color function to make a nice plot:

```
Clear[cf]
cf[z_] := Which[
z >= π/2, ColorData["Rainbow"][2 z/π - 1]
,
True,
GrayLevel[2 z/π]
];
```

A line and some constants:

```
 Clear[ft, gt];
 ft[t_] := t;
 gt[t_] := -.2 Sqrt[2.] t;

 i = .2 π;
 r = 1.02;
 l = .4 π;

 len = 107.;
 n = 200;
 pts = {Mod[ft[#], 2 π], Mod[gt[#], 2 π]} & /@ 
  Subdivide[0, len, 10 n];
 arrows = Select[
 Partition[{Mod[ft[#], 2 π], Mod[gt[#], 2 π]} & /@ 
 Subdivide[0, len, n], 2], Norm[#[[2]] - #[[1]]] <  π &];
```

Make the plot:

```
 ContourPlot[T[f, q, i, r, l], {f, 0, 2 π}, {q, 0, 2 π},
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ColorFunction -> cf,
  Contours -> Subdivide[0, π, 20],
  PlotRange -> {0, π},
  Epilog -> {
    Point[pts],
    {Red, Thick, Arrow[#] & /@ arrows}}
  ]
```

[image: Lines over the regions]

If you were to follow one of the lines as it wraps around, sometimes it is in the colored regions and sometimes it is not. I need to know the distribution of the lengths of the line segments that are in the colored region.

My current method:

It is easy to plot the value of the function along the line:

```
tmax = 100;
Plot[T[ft[t], gt[t], i, r, l], {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image: function along line]

To find all of the sections that are above $\frac{\pi}{2}$, I do the following:

```
 pic = Plot[T[ft[t], gt[t], i, r, l], {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotRange -> {π/2, All},
  Axes -> False
  ];

sec = Select[Cases[pic, Line[a_] :> a, ∞], 
  Length[#] > 3 &];

sec = {First[#], Last[#]} & /@ sec;
```

I make a plot of the function with the rage going from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ up to `All` then use `Case[]` to find the data points in the `Line[]` commands. And finally just take the endpoints of the `Line[]` paths.

Take care of the possible end cases if the function was above  $\frac{\pi}{2}$ at `t=0` or `t=tmax`

```
 ϵ = 10^-6;
 sec = Select[sec, 
   Chop[#[[1, 2]] - π/2, ϵ] == 0 && 
   Chop[#[[2, 2]] - π/2, ϵ] == 0 &];
```

Plot that shows it acuraly works:

```
 Plot[T[ft[t], gt[t], i, r, l], {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  Epilog -> {
    Line[#] & /@ sec
    }
  ]
```

[image: Function with line segments]

Finally: finding the distibutions of the segment lengths:

```
 ends = sec[[All, All, 1]];

  dT = #[[2]] - #[[1]] & /@ ends;

  Histogram[dT]
```

[image: distibution]

The issue with this is that as `tmax` grows without bound the plotting method starts to give bad results even when I increase `PlotPoints` and the amount of memory grows to the point of crashing the sub-kernels.

Are there better Mathematica ways of doing this? I have played with the `Region*` functions but I can never get them to work consistently.

Answer (score 2):

The `MeshFunctions` capability of `Plot[]` is one route you might want to explore.

An aside first: your `S` and `T` functions can be implemented quite compactly:

```
S[f_, q_, i_, r_] := EulerMatrix[{i, f, q}].{r, 0, 0};
T[f_, q_, i_, r_, l_] :=
  ArcCos[Normalize[S[f, q, i, r]].RotationMatrix[l, {0, 1, 0}].{1, 0, 0}]
```

From there,

```
ft[t_] := t
gt[t_] := -Sqrt[2] t/5

tmax = 100;
plt = With[{i = .2 π, r = 1.02, l = .4 π},
           Plot[T[ft[t], gt[t], i, r, l], {t, 0, tmax},
                Mesh -> {{π/2}}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}]]

ends = Partition[Sort[Cases[Normal[plt], Point[{x_, y_}] :> x, ∞]], 2];
dt = -(Subtract @@@ ends);
```

and running `Histogram[dT]` ought to yield the same figure. All of this assumes the number of crossing points is always even, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of using `Mash` and `MeshFunctions` which allows the explicit setting of the value in question.  But one still needs to test if the endpoints are the beginning of a segment with values greater than the value in question. One could check the derivative at the endpoints.
However, this method now requires `Plot` to generate all the data above and below the value in question and still does not scale well for very large `tmax` where the `Plot` function starts missing some of the oscillations.

Comment: "...where the `Plot` function starts missing some of the oscillations..." - that's where you try increasing `PlotPoints`.

Comment: Yes, I have but around `PlotPoints` of 90000 things go sour. I need a method that "moves along the function" as opposed to "calculate everything up front and take what I need". If nothing obvious comes up I'll just write my own that uses the `Pot` method and subdivides the domain into reasonable sizes.

Comment: "subdivides the domain into reasonable sizes." - I was going to suggest that next, but the bookkeeping involved in stitching together pieces of domains seems annoying.

Comment: Yes. which was the motivation for the question. I'm hoping for some Mathematica magic.